# Search the file inside folder or sub folder using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search the files inside the sub-folder of my network using VBA of excel. For the time being, I am able to make search upto the main folder `search`as shown in figure. For example if I search by writing `1_maual` pdf file in the excel file it will open the pdf file. Now I want to open the file inside the sub-folder like `Hello_1` because sub fodler are created manually and every time I could specify the sub folder path in the VBA code. So I am trying to write the VBA code to search the sub folder but I could not got the solution.

[image]

```
Public Const NETWORK_PATH As String = "C:\Users\WS035\Desktop\serach"
Public Const F_PATH20 As String = NETWORK_PATH

Function file_itiran(serchfile_path As String, key_word As String, fi_name() As String, file_num As Integer) As Integer
Dim str1, dir_ret As String

str1 = serchfile_path & key_word
dir_ret = Dir(str1, vbDirectory)
If dir_ret <> "" Then fi_name(file_num) = (serchfile_path & dir_ret)
While dir_ret <> ""
    dir_ret = Dir
    file_num = file_num + 1
    If dir_ret <> "" Then fi_name(file_num) = serchfile_path & dir_ret
Wend
file_itiran = file_num

End Function

Function GetSubfolders(folderPath As String) As Variant
Dim subfolders As Variant
Dim folder As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set folder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder(folderPath)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not folder Is Nothing Then
    subfolders = folder.subfolders
End If

GetSubfolders = subfolders
End Function

Function drawing_path1(hinban As String, f_name() As String) As Integer
Dim search_path As String
Dim file_num As Integer
Dim Filename As String
Dim subfolders As Variant
Dim subfolder As Object

file_num = 0

' Convert to uppercase and remove suffix
hinban = UCase(sufficdel(hinban))

' Search for files in the main folder
search_path = F_PATH20 & "\"
file_num = file_itiran(search_path, hinban & "*.*", f_name(), file_num)

' Search for files in subfolders
subfolders = GetSubfolders(F_PATH20)

If Not IsEmpty(subfolders) Then
    For Each subfolder In subfolders
        search_path = F_PATH20 & "\" & subfolder.Name & "\"
        file_num = file_itiran(search_path, hinban & "*.*", f_name(), file_num)
    Next subfolder
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple recursive set of functions that should work for you ...

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetFilesInFolder(ByVal strFolderPath As String)
    Dim objFSO As Object, objFolder As Object, objSubFolder As Object, objFile As Object
    
    ' Create a FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
    
    ' Loop through each file in the folder
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        Debug.Print objFile.Path
    Next
    
    ' Recursively process subfolders
    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.Subfolders
        GetFilesInFolder objSubFolder.Path
    Next
End Sub

Sub TestGetFilesInFolder()
    ' Specify the folder path you want to start from
    Dim strFolderPath As String
    
    strFolderPath = "C:\YourFolder"
    
    ' Call the recursive function to get files in the folder and its subfolders
    GetFilesInFolder strFolderPath
End Sub
```

... you'll just need to adapt it to work specifically for you.